# PowerShell: How to apply multiple filters via where-object cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

Is there a better way to filter for objects via `where-object` then to send the data through multiple pipelines?

```
$clients = Get-ADComputer 
                -SearchBase "OU=Clients,DC=contoso,DC=com" 
                -Filter * 
                -Properties Description,OperatingSystem

$clients | Where OperatingSystem -notlike "*Windows 7*" 
                 | Where OperatingSystem -notlike "*Windows 10*"
```

Ideal would be a complex filtering mechanism like we can use for the `-Filter` Parameter. I would have expected to be able to use something like the following...

```
$Clients | Where { 
    (OperatingSystem -notlike "Windows 7") -and (OperatingSystem -notlike "Windows 10")
}
```

Comment: `(OperatingSystem` -> `($_.OperatingSystem`

Comment: As @PetSerAl pointed out your issue is accessing the property correctly. -AND works fine in a Where-Object filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$clients | Where OperatingSystem -notlike "*Windows 7*" |
    Where OperatingSystem -notlike "*Windows 10*"
```

Strictly speaking, this should work.

However, the problem you're running in to is that the simplified `Where-Object` syntax shown above only works in the most simple cases.  When you use the full syntax, you must specify the properties using the `$_` variable:

```
$clients | Where-Object {
    ($_.OperatingSystem -notlike '*Windows 7*') -and ($_.OperatingSystem -notlike '*Windows 10*')
}
```

However, since you're using `Get-ADComputer`, you really should be using the `-Filter` property on that command.  It will be *much* faster, and will be less work for your domain controller, too:

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Clients,DC=contoso,DC=com" `
    -Filter "(OperatingSystem -notlike '*Windows 7*') -and (OperatingSystem -notlike '*Windows 10*')" `
    -Properties Description,OperatingSystem
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am aware of the burden put on the network and the domain controller. But to my apology I have to add, that I was doing further processing on the data, requiring more then just "Windows 7" objects, ... so pulling "all" data (noting the -searchBase restriction) was the better approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is more efficient to filter directly in the query rather than filtering after-the-fact using `Where-Object` (which retrieves all objects first). Example using the `-LDAPFilter` parameter:

```
Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(&(!operatingSystem=Windows 7*)(!operatingSystem=Windows 10*))" -Properties operatingSystem,description
```

Comment: This comes up so many times it should be in a PowerShell FAQ. Active Directory is a database. You would never retrieve all columns on all tables from your SQL database then filter it in application memory. LDAP is no different.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
$DesktopClients=@('Windows 7','Windows 10')
$Clients=$Clients -notmatch ($DesktopClients -join '|')
```